# Can't bring external domain to Azure Mobile App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

when I tried to bring a external domain to my Azure mobile app(xxname.azure-mobile.net), it comes out an error with message

"Failed to update hostname bindings:
The host names for the site must include the default hostname with dns suffix 'azurewebsites.net'. Currently specified hostnames are: 'xxname.azure-mobile.net,xxx.microsoft.com'."

Is it means that Azure doesn't support to bring external domain to mobile app? Only Web app can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two "standard" Azure-owned domains - the v1 mobile services uses xxx.azure-mobile.net - the v2 mobile apps uses xxx.azurewebsites.net.  You can, in addition, bring any domain that you own using the custom domains feature. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-custom-domain-name/

You can't bring an azure-mobile.net domain because you don't own it.  The only way to get a v2 mobile app with an azure-mobile.net domain name is to migrate it from a v1 mobile service.

Comment: Seems the problem is Azure does not allow me to bring a custom domain I own to a v1 mobile service(.azure-mobile.net), and the only way to do so is bring the custom domain to a v2 mobile service(.azurewebsites.net). That's what I guess...

Comment: Correct - v1 mobile services does not support custom domains.